# NetSuite PHP Toolkit Time Entry Search

Tags: php, netsuite, toolkit

```
<?php
// Token-based Authentication
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use NetSuite\NetSuiteService;


$config = array(
    // required -------------------------------------
    "endpoint" => "2019_1",
    "host"     => "https://webservices.netsuite.com",
    "email"    => "myemail@domain.com",
    "password" => "Mypassword",
    "role"     => "12345",
    "account"  => "7654321",
    "app_id"   => "XXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX",
);
$service = new NetSuiteService($config);
$service->setSearchPreferences(true, 20);

use NetSuite\Classes\SearchDateField;
use NetSuite\Classes\TimeEntrySearch;
use NetSuite\Classes\TimeEntrySearchBasic;
use NetSuite\Classes\TimeEntrySearchAdvanced;
use NetSuite\Classes\SearchRequest;



//Search Date
$SearchField = new SearchDateField();
$SearchField->searchValue = '2021-05-01T00:16:11+00:00';
$SearchField->operator = "after";
$ItemSearchBasic = new TimeEntrySearchBasic();
$ItemSearchBasic->lastModified = $SearchField;

$ItemSearch = new TimeEntrySearch();
$ItemSearch->basic = $ItemSearchBasic;

$search = new TimeEntrySearchAdvanced();
$search->columns = "TimeEntrySearchRow";
$search->criteria = $ItemSearch;
       
$request = new SearchRequest();
$request->searchRecord = $search;
    
$searchResponse = $service->search($request);
    echo "<pre>";print_r($searchResponse);die();
    if (!$searchResponse->searchResult->status->isSuccess) {
        echo "SEARCH ERROR";
    } else {
        echo "SEARCH SUCCESS, records found: " . $searchResponse->searchResult->totalRecords . "\n";
        $records = $searchResponse->searchResult->searchRowList->searchRow;
        
        foreach ($records as $record)  {
            echo "Name: " . $record->basic->name->searchValue . "\n";
        }
    
    }
?>
```

I'm trying to get the last Time Entry in NetSuite filter by lastModified operator "After", I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

The error message is: -> The ''Timesheets'' feature is not enabled in your NetSuite account.

What do I need to activate?

Comment: ___Sorry, but I have to ask___ Did you check that the ''Timesheets'' feature **is** enabled in your NetSuite account. **??**

Comment: **Or** that you are using the correct account! The one where the ''Timesheets'' feature is enabled

Comment: Would [this answer the question](https://www.abaci-us.com/new-user-interface-weekly-timesheet/) _What do I need to activate?_

Comment: The report that I'm trying to reach is Transactions->Employees->Track Time->List, and the API user is an admin. I have activated already "New Weekly timesheet interface", but I still get the same issue. I wonder if is something in my role to be activated.

Answer (score 0):

Please use token based Authentication instead of APP ID and also the host should match with the SOAP URL mentioned under company information. Below is the config file screen shot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXNSo.png)